# Java - For loop not executing when trying to search ArrayList

Tags: java, loops, for-loop, arraylist

this is my first question on stack overflow but I have some experience in Java. I am making a Java application at the moment (575 lines and counting!) and am trying to search through an ArrayList for a string. But **I do not want it to be exact!** Let me clarify: I want to iterate through each ArrayList element and search that string for another string. if the string is found in the ArrayList element, (for now) I want it printed to the console. I hope I have been clear enough.
Following is the relevant code. All variables are defined and the code compiles, just no output (from the search function) is printed. I am pretty sure that it is because the for loop doesn't execute, but I am puzzled as to why.

```
//the keylistener that calls the search() function, attached to a JTextField that the query is entered into
class searchFieldListener implements KeyListener {
    searchFieldListener() {
    }
    public void keyTyped(KeyEvent event) {
        if (event.getID() == KeyEvent.KEY_TYPED) {
            query = searchField.getText()+Character.toString(event.getKeyChar());
            System.out.println(query);
            for (i = 0; i == nameList.size(); i++) {
                search(query, i);
            }
        }
    }
    public void keyReleased(KeyEvent event) {

    }
    public void keyPressed(KeyEvent event) {

    }
}

//the troublesome search() function
void search(String query, int iter) {
    searchString = nameList.get(iter);
    System.out.println(searchString);

    if (searchString.indexOf(query) != -1) {
        System.out.println(Integer.toString(iter));
    } else {
        System.out.println("not found \n");
    }
}
```

Variables/Objects and uses:

- **searchFieldListener**
  The KeyListener for the JTextField called searchField for obvious reasons.
- **query**
  The string of the text to be searched for.
- **i**
  Why does everyone use i in loops? I guess it's a coding tradition.
- **nameList**
  The ArrayList of names (well, duh).
- **searchString**
  The string to be searched in (as in, try to find *query* in *searchString*).
- **iter**
  The number of iterations the for loop has been through so far.

  ---

  Once again I hope I have been clear enough. Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The reason why your for loop is not executing is because of the condition used in the loop:

```
for (i = 0; i == nameList.size(); i++) 
              ^^
```

Since the [**size**](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#size%28%29) method of the ArrayList class returns the number of elements you might want to have
`i < nameList.size()` instead.

Comment: thanks! It's amazing how quickly people replied! Same to everyone else who answered, I really, REALLY appreciate it.

Answer (score 2):

```
for (i = 0; i == nameList.size(); i++)
```

should be

```
for (i = 0; i < nameList.size(); i++)
```

Not sure if you need < or <= though, you just modify it to you needs.

Answer (score 2):

have have a typo in your for-loop. shouldn't this:

```
for (i = 0; i == nameList.size(); i++) {
```

look like this:

```
for (i = 0; i < nameList.size(); i++) {
```

Answer (score 2):

Several correct answers, but one aspect is missing:

```
for (i = 0; i < nameList.size(); i++)
```

This is an old-school loop. Starting from Java 1.5, you should use this idiom to iterate over an array or iterable (a List is an Iterable):

```
for(String s: strings){

}
```

This simpler syntax is a) much less error-prone and b) a common way to iterate over many different data structures, including arrays and collections.

Internally this is a shortcut for this code:

```
for(Iterator<String> it = strings.iterator(); it.hasNext();){
    String s = it.next();
    // your code here
}
```

Comment: ahh.. have heard about these special for loops and will research and put into practice.